# Erro ao executar o JSF

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Estou com um erro no JSF que não consigo descobrir. Parece que é com meu produto DAO ou Produto. Isso estava acontencendo quando estava gravando um produto, agora, o projeto nem abre mais.

```
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Informações:   visiting unvisited references
Grave:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
Grave:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/loogix__pm), (applicationName=loogix) }
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/loogix__pm), (applicationName=loogix) }
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
```

Segue as minhas classes que fazer o caminho para gravar um produto.

### Formulário que grava um produto:

```
<h:form>
                    <div class="message-box scroll">
                        <div class="message-in container-fluid p-l-3 p-r-3">

                            <div class="clearfix m-t-3">
                                <h:outputLabel for="codigo" value="Código" rendered="false"/>
                                <h:inputText value="#{produtoController.produto.codigo}" id="codigo" class="form-control" required="true" pt:placeholder="Digite o codigo do produto"/>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="clearfix m-t-1">
                                <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" rendered="false"/>
                                <h:inputText value="#{produtoController.produto.nome}" id="nome" class="form-control" required="true" pt:placeholder="Digite o nome do produto"/>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="clearfix m-t-1">
                                <h:outputLabel for="descricao" value="Descrição" rendered="false"/>
                                <h:inputTextarea value="#{produtoController.produto.descricao}" id="descricao" class="form-control" required="true" pt:placeholder="Descrição do produto"/>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="clearfix m-t-1">
                                <h:commandButton action="#{produtoController.gravar()}" value="Gravar produto" class="btn btn-success form-control" />
                            </div>
                            


                        </div><!-- /.message-out -->

                        
                    </div><!-- /.message-in -->
                    
                </h:form>
```

Ao ir para esta página, eu acesso inico uma instancia no meu **ProdutoController.java**

```
public String novo() {
        this.produto = new Produto();
        this.alterando = false;
        return "novo-produto?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Para gravar, uso:

```
public String gravar() {
        
        if (this.alterando == false)
            this.daoProduto.add(this.produto);
        else
            this.daoProduto.update(this.produto);
        
        this.produtos = this.daoProduto.getList();
        
        return "produto?faces-redirect=true"; 
}
```

Meu **ProdutoDAO**:

```
public class ProdutoDAO {
    
    private GenericDAO<Produto> dao;
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.dao = new GenericDAO<Produto>(this.em);
    }
    
    public void add(Produto produto) {
        this.dao.add(produto);
    }
    
    public void update(Produto produto) {
        this.dao.update(produto);
    }
    
    public void delete(Produto produto) {
        this.dao.delete(produto);
    }
    
    public List<Produto> getList() {
        Query q = this.em.createQuery("select p from Produto p");
        return q.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Eu uso uma classe genérica, pois posso ter milhares de DAO, e alterar o básico:

```
public class GenericDAO<T> {
    
    
    private EntityManager em;

    public GenericDAO(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    
    public void add(T t) {
        this.em.persist(t);
    }
    
    public void update(T t) {
        this.em.merge(t);
    }
    
    public void delete(T t) {
        this.em.remove(t);
    }
    
}
```

Minha classe **Produto.java** está da seguinte forma:

```
@Entity
public class Produto implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String descricao;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "produto")
    private List<ProdutoAlmoxarifado> produtoAlmoxarifados;

    public Produto() {
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    
    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public List<ProdutoAlmoxarifado> getProdutos() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(produtoAlmoxarifados);
    }

    public void addProdutoAlmoxarifado(ProdutoAlmoxarifado produtoAlmoxarifado) {
        this.produtoAlmoxarifados.add(produtoAlmoxarifado);
        produtoAlmoxarifado.setProduto(this);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Produto{" + "id=" + id + ", codigo=" + codigo + ", nome=" + nome + ", descricao=" + descricao + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Produto other = (Produto) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    
    
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a localizar esse erro?

Comment: Posta seu arquivo persistence.xml

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Douglas: Segue https://github.com/fsmaAcademy/loogix/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: onde você configurou as informações do seu database ?

Comment: Esta neste arquivo: https://github.com/fsmaAcademy/loogix/blob/master/src/main/setup/glassfish-resources.xml

Comment: Isso aqui tá certo? `jndiName=java:app/jdbc/loogix__pm`

Comment: Então... o glassfish que gerou automaticamente... o certo é: jndiName=java:app/jdbc/loogix...
ainda não sei o motivo de ele estar gerando isso...